# Why is require different from setq in multiple arguments?

Tags: elisp

If you want to use `require`, you can only use the following:

```
(require 'foo)
(require 'bar)
```

But you can't do the following:

```
(require 'foo
         'bar)
```

Would it not be more easier and faster if `require` accepts the argument structure in the same way as `setq` does:

```
  (setq foo t
        bar t)
```

Comment: This question seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) The OP probably needs a way to avoid repetitive code.

Comment: This doesn't seem opinion-based to me, though removing the "wouldn't this be easier" phrasing would help. I read the question as why `require` doesn't behave like `setq`, and the answer that @Drew and I both came up with is that `require` has additional features of which the OP was likely not aware.

Comment: It is like asking why any function at all doesn't work like `setq` for which there are numerous answers. It is also important to note that the variadic signature of `setq` is considered a misfeature by many, including the maintainer of emacs.

Comment: Fair enough - though I'd say the detail about `setq` being considered a misfeature is a really interesting answer as well. :-) I still think the question of "why does require only accept a single package name rather than n names" is reasonable. But apparently the OP was not actually asking that, since the accepted answer is an answer to "how do I avoid repeating this code". The question should probably be revised accordingly.

Comment: `setq` and `require` behave differently because they are two totally unrelated functions. Also note that the "newly" added `setq-local` does not allow setting multiple variables, because the Emacs maintainer considers it a mistake that `setq` behaves that way (but has to keep it that way for backward compatibility). And most importantly *please* use `require` once for each feature. Don't use a loop, don't use a macro. There are tools that assume that features are always required using one require form per feature.

Comment: @tarsius I am not aware of "There are tools that assume that features are always required using one require form per feature.". What are you referring to?

Comment: Tarsius, I would like to hear why I need to require once for each feature? I could easily remove it in the list, as stated in the answer of kaushalmodi.

Comment: If we're talking about one's personal init file, IIRC the same emacs maintainer said it's usually best to use `load` instead of `require`.

Comment: I'll try not to put words into his mouth, so here's the exact wording (which is different from what I wrote but I can't edit anymore) https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2015-02/msg00821.html

Comment: The main reason I would strongly recommend against using `dolist` is that I see absolutely no benefit in replacing "needless duplication" with "a little bit of extra cognitive overhead". When I see a block of require forms, I immediately see what is going on *and* what features are being required. When I see a top-level `dolist` with a `require` as body, it takes me a bit of time to realize that, and then I wonder why that is being done. I then have to check whether we are looping over a constant (quoted) list of features or whether some function is being called to provide the list.

Comment: Then I can finally parse the list of features.

Comment: Regarding the "tools that need (require 'feature)": I extract metadata from all packages on the Emacsmirror, including the required and provided features. Because loading all packages (and then asking Emacs what features are required and provided by a library) would be insecure (and in many cases would fail) I have to extract the features using text search.

Comment: Tarsius, clearly enough. However, I liked the `dolist` feature, because it makes my init.el more robust. So I'm trying it if you don't mind it. I would like to thank you for your answer, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`dolist`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/dolist.html) to avoid repetitive code if you like.

```el
(dolist (pkg '(pkg1 pkg2 pkg3))
  (require pkg))
```

Above will be equivalent to:

```el
(require 'pkg1)
(require 'pkg2)
(require 'pkg3)
```

The advantage is that you can also specify the identical arguments you might need to pass to a bunch of `require`s:

```el
(dolist (pkg '(pkg1 pkg2 pkg3))
  (require pkg nil :noerror))
```

Answer (score 4):

`require` already accepts additional arguments.  In particular, you can do a "soft" require this way:

```
(require 'foo nil t) ; No error raised if library foo is not available
```

Nothing special would be gained by letting you do:

```
(require 'foo  nil nil
         'bar  nil nil
         'toto nil nil)
```

(You can easily write your own macro to do what you request, however.)

Answer (score 3):

That might be more convenient in the simple case of just listing a bunch of features to load. Note however that `require` can take some optional arguments:

From the doc string (with some stuff elided):

> (require FEATURE &optional FILENAME NOERROR)
>
> If feature FEATURE is not loaded, load it from FILENAME...If FILENAME
> is omitted, the printname of FEATURE is used as the file name... If
> the optional third argument NOERROR is non-nil, then return nil if the
> file is not found instead of signaling an error...